# Runing sh scripts in system startup, files not available error while running in root

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, scripts, cron

I am a newbie in Ubuntu 20.04. I have a file structure for an application as -

Home-->Folder1-->execute.sh,main.py, utils.py, ui.py etc..

What i intend to do is run the execute.sh file on system startup. The lines in my execute.sh file are :

```
export PATH="/home/Folder1"
python3 -m venv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install python-dotenv
python /home/Folder1/main.py
```

I tried a cron job `cron -e` to put a line `sh \home\Folder1\execute.sh`, and start the process but could not make it work. On further check, I have seen that when i access root and try to run `sh \home\Folder1\execute.sh` throws error `main.py not found`. I have to `cd` into `\home\Folder1` and then execute `sh execute.sh` to make it run. What will be the best way to achieve this in system reboot each time automatically?

Comment: One way would be to run the job with cron but using you user rather than root. The root user runs in a different environment so from that perspective things are not where you expect them to be. Alternatively use the complete path to each program wherever referenced

Comment: @Raffa, shall look into it if I can use cron as you said. can you elaborate on the last part?

Comment: @PonJar, yea one solution will be to refer full path to all modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is wrong on many levels :)** ... but, it's OK, we'll make it right together.

#### First level

[`cron`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/cron.8.html) is a daemon/service to execute scheduled commands ... You **don't** add your cron jobs to it ... you [add your cron jobs](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368) to your user's `crontab` like so:

```
crontab -e
```

or to root's `crontab` like so:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

It will then be executed by `cron` automatically ... That's it.

#### Second level

`sh \home\Folder1\execute.sh` is a Windows style path which is not valid on Ubuntu and will translate to a single filename(not a path) like so:

```
sh homeFolder1execute.sh
```

it should be with the forward slash `/` and not the backward slash e.g. :

```
sh /home/Folder1/execute.sh
```

#### Third level

Your `export PATH="/home/Folder1"` is not the correct usage that might yield the result you expect of adding `/home/Folder1` to PATH ... instead it will replace everything already in the environment variable PATH with just `/home/Folder1` and that is another problem ... to just add `/home/Folder1`, you should do it like so:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/Folder1"
```

#### Bonus level

As a general advice, when using `crontab` in general and the root's `crontab` in particular, specify the full path to the executable/s on your system(you can find it with e.g. `which sh`) like so:

```
/usr/bin/sh /home/Folder1/execute.sh
```

also use the full path to executables that are used in your script e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv
```

and:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/Folder1/main.py
```

and:

```
/usr/bin/pip install python-dotenv
```

*Although, for the last two, it will work with just `python` and `pip` in a python virtual environment like you do in your script.*

Otherwise, the running shell might fail in finding the path to your command/s as for example [the root's environment variable PATH will return different paths from those returned by your user's PATH environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/219692).

You can, however, save specifying the full path to your script file along with other scripts/files sourced/referenced in it by, first, `cd`ing to the directory containing it in the crontab line like so:

```
cd /home/Folder1 && /usr/bin/sh execute.sh
```

That wont save you from not providing the full path to the executables on your system i.e. like `/usr/bin/sh`, you still need to provide those ... why not the full path to `cd`? you might ask ... well, the answer is `cd` [is a builtin shell command](https://askubuntu.com/q/532788) and will work just fine without needing a path.

Comment: A `cd` statement `&&` executing full path sh as you pointed out, worked. Thank you. Now the process gets initiated in cron. However, I have one more concern, the application still does not start due to netifaces module could not connect to ethernet and get a ip. Error is in following line -- `ip = ni.ifaddresses(os.environ.get("NETWORK_MODE", "eth0"))[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']`. Error is 
`KeyError: 2`. It works fine if I run it from terminal. I tried `@reboot sleep 120 && cd .....&& sh`. Hoping that it will start after two minutes atleast but could not.

Comment: @mrin9san You probably need to install that module in the venv you run your python script in … the virtual env is self contained and it will not be enough to have that module only installed in the system wide python but in the venv as well.

Comment: @mrin9san Read [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-keyerror-2) as well … and if you can’t fix it, then post a new question with your code and the error message and explain how you run your code and the expected result so we can help you.