# Running scripts on startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I am trying to run a script as soon as my system starts. I am running ubuntu server version on an odroid M1. The script itself works when I use the command: `./StartJupyterNotebook.sh`.
However as soon as I try to call the script via crontab during a reboot nothing happens.

I modified the crontab with: crontab -e and to this I added the following code:

`@reboot /home/odroid/Scripts/StartJupyterNotebook.sh`.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need network working in the script ? You should add debug stuff like `bash -x` and a log file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Depending on permissions required by your script you might need to add it to root’s crontab with `sudo crontab -e` … This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1415391

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add your script to Cron list and schedule it to run in normal environment and not when the system reboots.
2. There may be a permission issue. Add your script to Cron list with the root user so that it runs when the system reboots.
3. Also, make sure the **cron service** is configured to automatically start at boot.

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable cron.service
   ```